# Safari won't see/show the web inspector of my app's WebView (WKWebView or UiWebView)

Tags: safari, uiwebview, wkwebview, inspection

I have been working on my appliance years now, and as always using the Safari's Web Inspector.
But today my Mac's Safari Inspector won't show/see anymore my App's webview, anyone have a clue about what could it be?

[image]

MacOS: 13.3.1
Processor: M1 Pro
iOS: 16.4.1
App Target Minimum iOS Version: 13.0

P.S.: the MacOS safari is still able to inspect my iPhone safari, but anymore on my app.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After reading some articles, I found out that Apple created one attribute on the WebView protocol, so from the iOS 16.4 or newer, you need to make the web inspection available like this:

Swift

```
if #available(macOS 13.3, iOS 16.4, tvOS 16.4, *) {
    webView.isInspectable = true
}
```

Objective-C

```
if (@available(macOS 13.3, iOS 16.4, tvOS 16.4, *)) {
    _webView.inspectable = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [more info](https://webkit.org/blog/13936/enabling-the-inspection-of-web-content-in-apps/)

Also if you use Cordova 
Cordova team fix this bug with the release of Cordova platform iOS 6.3.0 (see Cordova blog post: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2023/04/15/cordova-ios-release-6.3.0.html)

Comment: As this answer only contains additional information to the accepted answer, this answer should have been added as a comment to the accepted answer.